# WPF PRISM 6 DelegateComand ObservesCanExecute

Tags: wpf, prism, delegatecommand

Thanks in advance!

How should I use ObservesCanExecute in the DelegateCommand of PRISM 6?

```
public partial class  UserAccountsViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DelegateCommand InsertCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand UpdateCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand DeleteCommand { get; private set; }

    public UserAccount SelectedUserAccount
    {
        get;
        set
        {
            //notify property changed stuff
        }
    }

    public UserAccountsViewModel()
    {
        InitCommands();
    }

    private void InitCommands()
    {
        InsertCommand = new DelegateCommand(Insert, CanInsert);  
        UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Update,CanUpdate).ObservesCanExecute(); // ???
        DeleteCommand = new DelegateCommand(Delete,CanDelete);
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------

    private void Update()
    {
        //...
    }

    private bool CanUpdate()
    {
        return SelectedUserAccount != null;
    }

    //.....
}
```

Unfortunatelly, I'm not familiar with expressions in c#. Also, I thought this would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ObservesCanExecute()` works “mostly like” the `canExecuteMethod` parameter of `DelegateCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)`.

However, if you have a **boolean property** instead of a **method**, you don't need to define a `canExecuteMethod` with `ObservesCanExecute`.

In your example, suppose that `CanUpdate` is not a **method**, just suppose that it's a **boolean property**.

Then you can change the code to `ObservesCanExecute(() => CanUpdate)` and the `DelegateCommand` will execute only if the `CanUpdate` boolean property evaluates to `true` (no need to define a method).

`ObservesCanExecute` is like a “shortcut” over a property instead of having to define a method and having passing it to the `canExecuteMethod` parameter of the `DelegateCommand` constructor.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just use a lambda here? The only thing I can think is that there is some caching of the resolves expression.

Comment: @Gusdor, as alphe said, It's because the ObserveCanExecute loosely replaces the [CanExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654646.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) Boolean method; therefore, it has to return a Boolean value.